# Tablet with only USB 3.0 ports, can't connect keyboard or mouse after fresh Windows 7 install

Tags: windows-7, usb, keyboard, mouse, tablet

I recently installed Windows 7 on my tablet, and I can't get passed the login screen because I have no way to use a mouse or keyboard.  My USB mouse and keyboard work just fine in the BIOS, but as soon as Windows 7 boots up, they stop.  After googling around for a bit, it looks like it's a problem with the 3.0 ports, and everyone recommends using a 2.0 port. I just don't have any 2.0 ports to try that with. Only 1 3.0 port. Does anyone have any ideas I can try?

Answer (score 1):

Download this Intel utility to install usb 3.0 drivers to the W7 bootable usb drive you make. The Install W7.

Not sure if this is only for Intel usb 3.0 or works with all usb 3.0 chips

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25476/Windows-7-USB-3-0-Creator-Utility

[image]